# SQLite pathway iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite, select

I'm trying to access to my table in my SQLite using this code :

```
fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"movieData.sqlite"];

    if(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK){

        const char *sql = "SELECT movieName FROM myMovies";
        sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare(db, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement");
        }
```

My output is "Problem with prepare statement". I'm pretty sure about my table name and other things in the *sql. But still doesn't work. any idea guys ?!

Comment: In `sqlite3_open()` you pass `&database`, however, in `sqlite3_prepare()`, you pass `&db`. Is that a typo, or are you just writing pseudo-code? Furthermore, have you actualliy copied the database file into the app bundle? In addition, you should really use `sqlite3_prepare_v2()`, and if nothing works, you can try out my [SQL wrapper class.](http://github.com/H2CO3/SQLHelper)

Comment: found the solution , cheers mate

Answer (score 0):

added

```
BOOL success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
    if(!success)
    {
        NSLog(@"Cannot locate database file '%@'.", dbPath);
    }
    if(!(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK))
    {
        NSLog(@"An error has occured.");
    }
```

just before `cont char *sql` and it's working now :)